# Oracle SQLScript to match columns

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

Currently I'm working on a task to join the columns of 2 tables & match them and update in the third column whether they are matching or not.

```
select a.ID,a.NAME,b.NAME from TABLEA a join TABLEB B on a.ID=b.ID;
```

[image: This is how table looks after join]

So, my first row is matching & 2nd one is not.
I want to create a third col which matches these col and produce result in third col (IS_MATCHED) in the form of true or false.

How to do this??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option is to use `case` expression.

Sample data:

```
SQL> with
  2  tablea (id, name) as
  3    (select 1, 'utkarsh' from dual union all
  4     select 2, 'vedansh' from dual
  5    ),
  6  tableb (id, name) as
  7    (select 1, 'utkarsh' from dual union all
  8     select 2, 'rahul'   from dual
  9    )
```

Query begins here:

```
 10  select a.id, a.name, b.name,
 11    --
 12    case when a.name = b.name then 'match'
 13         else null
 14    end is_matched
 15  from tablea a join tableb b on a.id = b.id;

        ID NAME    NAME    IS_MATCHED
---------- ------- ------- ----------
         1 utkarsh utkarsh match
         2 vedansh rahul

SQL>
```

Comment: one more ques...what to do if few more fields r there along with name which needs to be matched

Comment: You'd add them into the same CASE expression, e.g. `case when a.name = b.name and a.address = b.address and a.phone = b.phone then 'match' ...`

Comment: How to access this column is_matched if we want to perform some operations on it??

Comment: Two options: **a)** as the whole expression, or **b)** use current query (lines #10-15) as a CTE, and then you can reference is by its alias.